# Как загрузить все недостающие модули в node js?

Tags: node.js, npm

Я пишу скрипт на node js и устанавливаю библиотеки с помощью команды

> npm i name_lib

И после переноса проекта я не хочу копировать всю папку **node_modules**

Я помню что есть возможность забрать только файлы js которые создавал сам и package.json + package-lock.json и какой-то командой запустить загрузку всех необходимых модулей.

Как это сделать? Буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: Так и загрузить `npm i`, без имени пакетов.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg спасибо! это то что мне было нужно :)